# How can I get from Marrakech to Kasbah Du Toubkal?

Tags: morocco, marrakech

My friends and I want to visit Kasbah Du Toubkal from Marrakech about 24th February. Since I haven't found any information about possibilities of travel and prices there, I would like to ask you for advice.

Could you tell me how much it would be from Marrakech to Kasbah Du Toubkal? By bus or taxi, whatever.

I've searched for accommodation (one night) there, in Kasbah Du Toubkal and I've found (on Booking.com) that it would be about €16 for three people per night. Is it possible?

Comment: Rome2Rio only suggests [using a taxi](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Marrakesh/Imlil-Atlas-Mountains), so your options look pretty limited.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Rome2Rio says that it should be about 200 Dirhams from Marrakech to Kasbah Du Toubkal. In what meaning? Per person or for one car? If there is three of us, should we count with one third of the price Rome2Rio says? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kasbah du Toubkal's website suggests one of three options:

1. A private transfer arranged by Kasbah du Toubkal (EUR 85)
2. A taxi (starting at EUR 30, depending on bargaining skills)
3. A shared taxi (starting at EUR 3-5, depending on bargaining skills)

Source: http://www.kasbahdutoubkal.com/kasbah/directions.html